# ProvideX PVX+ SQL Case Statement

Tags: sql, case-statement

Does ProvideX PVX+ support a case statement using the ODBC driver? I am currently writing it like the following:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN IC_UM_BY_ITEM.OK_SELLING = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isdefault
FROM IC_UM_BY_ITEM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, ProvideX doesn't support CASE statements. A list of supported functions are available here:

[PVX+ ProvideX manual](http://manual.pvxplus.com/)

In the manual, navigate to "PxPlus ODBC Driver > Using the ODBC Driver > Scalar Functions" for a list of functions that work in ProvideX queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response and link to the manual, Alex. I ended up having to writing separate queries for each case.